# Unit Test Spring MVC Controller Using Jmockit

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit, jmockit

I am trying to Unit Test a Spring MVC Controller. But don’t know how to do it. So can anyone tell me how to Unit Test a Spring Web MVC Controller using JMockit

Answer (score 1):

Use Spring MockMvc to write unit test cases for controller.
Refer https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/MockMvc.html